# Grammar with no left recursive rules

Tags: computer-science

Let G be the grammar :

```
S --> A | B

A --> aaB | Aab | Aba

B --> bB | Bb | aba
```

construct a new grammar G' that contains no left recursive rules and is equivalent to G.

This is the answer i came up with, but i brought it to my professor and he advised me it was wrong. He refused to tell me how to fix it because it is has to be turned in for a grade later. All help is appreciated.
I AM VERY CONFUSED ON THIS, AND ALL INSIGHT IS GREATLY APPRECIATED

```
GL: S0→ S | λ
S→ ABC | AB
A→ aA | a
B→ bB | A
C→ cC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
S -> A | B
A -> aaC
C -> bC | D
D -> abaE
E -> bE | F
F -> λ | ab | ba
B -> bB | G
G -> aba | H
H -> b | bH
```

Comment: are you confident this contains no left recursive rules?